# How to write a SQL like query with table column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to write a SQL like query with table column ?

I have two tables table1 and table2.

```
Table1 has Notes
Table2 has billid
```

We have around 100 bills which satisfies Like condition.

Right now, i am writing with Static value on the column.

How should i write a Like Query by passing Column in the Like Condition.

```
select * from table1
where Notes like select billid from table2
```

Comment: It is a little unclear. Could you add some examples of data and the desired result?

Comment: Show a proper sample of data and the expected result  please

Comment: Is column1 the same values as Billid

Comment: @Javier, i have remodified the script. is it helpful. I just need the dynamic like condition. right now, i am passing one value by values

Comment: Just found out that StackOverflow, has (in good taste and form) disallowed lmgtfy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wanting a `JOIN` here.

If the exact `BillID` is found in `Table1.Column1` then:

```
select table1.*
from table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 ON
        table1.column1=table2.billid
```

You could also do this using `IN` in the WHERE clause if you truly don't need any records from your `table2` in the result set:

```
select *
from table1
where column1 in (SELECT billid FROM table2);
```

Which is pretty close to what you were aiming for in your attempted query.

Lastly, if you actually mean `LIKE` which is more of a wildcard match in SQL terms where the `column1` merely has to contain a `billid` then back to the join:

```
select table1.*
from table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 ON
        table1.column1 LIKE '%' + table2.billid + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Select a raw from table1 if any match from table2 exists

```
select *
from table1 
where exists (select billid 
              from  table2 
              where table1.column1 LIKE '%' + table2.billid + '%')
```